# Spring Security - Once logged in , browser do not asking for login details again

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring security 3.1 along with Spring 3.

I am facing a problem where I am logging in to the system using one browser ,  I am able to log into the system.And if I copy the same URL from here to other browser, there it is not asking the user to enter user credentials again. The problem is it is not showing login screen.

Here is my app-cofig.xml

```
    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to 
    configure as beans -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="CltSearch_signonRq" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.SignonRq">
    <property name="clientApp" ref="CltSearch_clientApp" />
</bean>

<bean id="CltSearch_clientApp" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.ClientApp">
    <property name="name" value="S3" />
</bean>

<bean id="signonRq" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.SignonRq">
    <property name="clientApp" ref="clientApp" />
    <property name="signonPswd" ref="signonPswd" />
</bean>
<bean id="signonPswd" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.SignonPswd">
    <property name="custId" ref="custId" />
    <property name="custPswd" ref="custPswd" />
</bean>
<bean id="custId" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.CustId">
</bean>
<bean id="custPswd" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.CustPswd">
</bean>


<bean id="clientApp" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.ClientApp">
    <property name="name" value="XCA" />
</bean>

<bean id="oXMapper" class="com.csc.exceed.util.OXMapper">
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="unmarshaller" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="acordRequest" ref="acordRequest" />
    <property name="acordResponse" ref="acordResponse" />
</bean>

<bean id="unmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
    <property name="mappingLocation"
        value="classpath:/templates/mapping/ACORD_Response_Mapping.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
    <property name="mappingLocation"
        value="classpath:/templates/mapping/ACORD_Request_Mapping.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="acordRequest" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.ACORD">
    <property name="insuranceSvcRq" ref="insuranceSvcRq" />
    <property name="signonRq" ref="CltSearch_signonRq" />
</bean>

<bean id="insuranceSvcRq" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.InsuranceSvcRq">
    <property name="com_csc_ClientSearchRq" ref="com_csc_ClientSearchRq" />
</bean>

<bean id="com_csc_ClientSearchRq"
    class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.Com_csc_ClientSearchRq">
    <property name="com_csc_SearchInfo" ref="com_csc_SearchInfo" />
</bean>

<bean id="com_csc_SearchInfo" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.Com_csc_SearchInfo">
    <property name="com_csc_SearchCriteria" ref="com_csc_SearchCriteria" />
</bean>

<bean id="com_csc_SearchCriteria"
    class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.Com_csc_SearchCriteria">
    <property name="com_csc_ClientSearch" ref="com_csc_ClientSearch" />
</bean>

<bean id="com_csc_ClientSearch" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.Com_csc_ClientSearch">
</bean>

<bean id="acordResponse" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.AcordResponse" />

<bean id="postXmlToUrl" class="com.csc.exceed.util.PostXmlToUrl" />

<bean id="supportData" class="com.csc.exceed.util.SupportDataUtilityImpl" />

<bean id="logging" class="com.csc.exceed.aspect.logging.LoggingAspect">
</bean>

<bean id="searchHandler" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.web.AccountSearchHandler">
    <property name="oXMapper" ref="oXMapper" />
    <property name="applicationProperties" ref="applicationProperties" />
    <property name="messageProperties" ref="messageProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="exceptionHandling" class="com.csc.exceed.aspect.exception.ExceptionHandling">
</bean>

<bean id="applicationProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:/config/application.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:/config/MessageResources.properties
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="xmlReader" class="com.csc.exceed.util.Validator">
    <property name="messageProperties" ref="messageProperties" />
    <property name="applicationProperties" ref="applicationProperties" />
    <property name="validationXml" value="classpath:/rules/validation-rules.xml" />
    <property name="oXMapper" ref="oXMapper" />
</bean>

<bean id="login" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.ACORD">
    <property name="signonRq" ref="signonRq" />
</bean>

<bean id="userManagerService" class="com.csc.exceed.aspect.security.UserManagerService" />
<bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
    class="com.csc.exceed.aspect.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider">

    <property name="userManagerService" ref="userManagerService"></property>
    <property name="oXMapper" ref="oXMapper" />
    <property name="applicationProperties" ref="applicationProperties" />
    <property name="messageProperties" ref="messageProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="customAuthenticationManager"
    class="com.csc.exceed.aspect.security.CustomAuthenticationManager">

    <property name="authenticationProvider" ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    <property name="oXMapper" ref="oXMapper" />
    <property name="login" ref="login" />
</bean>

<cache:annotation-driven />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />
</bean>

<bean id="ehcache"
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/config/ehcache.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="checkSession" class="com.csc.exceed.util.CheckSession">
    <property name="messageProperties" ref="messageProperties" />
</bean>


<security:http entry-point-ref="CMSAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
        ref="customizedFormLoginFilter" />
    <security:session-management
        session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />


    <security:intercept-url pattern="/certs/signin/**"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/certs/AccountSearch/**"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />


</security:http>
<bean id="sas"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy" />

<bean id="CMSAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="com.csc.exceed.aspect.accesscontrol.CMSAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/certs/signin" />
    <property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="customizedFormLoginFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="customAuthenticationManager" />
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/certs/j_spring_security_check" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="simpleURLSuccessHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="simpleURLFailureHandler" />
    <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true" />
    <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />

</bean>


<bean id="simpleURLFailureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/certs/signin" />
    <!-- <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true" /> -->
</bean>

<bean id="simpleURLSuccessHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/certs/AccountSearch" />
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true" />


</bean>
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And the web.xml is

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Enables Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/certs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Maven dependency tree is

Comment: What's the "other" browser? Do you mean you can log in with Safari, exit Safari, and access pages in Firefox without being prompted to log in? Or do you mean you can log in with IE8, close that window, open another IE8 window, and access pages?

Comment: @gatkin yes,this thing is happening in the above case. log in with Safari, exit Safari, and access pages in Firefox without being prompted to log in..he is my teammate

Comment: @gatkin It is happening in same as well as across browers.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess without actually looking at your classes. But maybe your `CustomAuthenticationProvider` - which is [singleton](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton) by default - is keeping the first logged in user object in memory instead of looking at the [security context](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e1518). 
You didn't say, but I guess when you open the second browser, the logged in user panel (if there's any) shows the user that was logged in the first browser, right?